# How can I browse transparent white icons in macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, icons, png, transparent, macos-mojave

In prior versions of macOS I was able to use Automator to add a thumbnail to the icon and then change the Finder background color, as in [How can I browse white icons in mac os x finder mavericks](https://superuser.com/questions/707530/how-can-i-browse-white-icons-in-mac-os-x-finder-mavericks). However, this does nothing in Mojave. Has anyone come up with a way to view white transparent (png) icons in Mojave? Alternatively, is there an app that will display these correctly?

This is how they look in Mojave:

[image]

This is how they look in prior versions (which is what I want):

[image]

Comment: did you find a fix?

Comment: No. I have an old Mac that I hadn’t upgraded, so I ended up using it to run the Automated script, then copying them back to my Mac Pro

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I'll look into the automated script =)